# Passing null while passing URL using bundle in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, bundle

Here what I am doing get URL from an `onPostExecute` method and passing it to next fragment using bundle.
My problem is that, I am executing `Show_data()` before passing data to fragment. Then why it is given null to bundle.
A second thing, Can I call youtube fragment inside `onPostExecute`?

```
public class Tab2Frag extends Fragment {

    public static String PRO_ID;
    public static String youtube_url1;

    MainActivity mainActivity;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab2, container, false);
        new Show_data().execute();
        new Adds1().execute();

        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putString("youtube_details", youtube_url1);
        System.out.println("@@2@@@"+youtube_url1);
        YouTubeFragmentActivity youTubeFragmentActivity=new YouTubeFragmentActivity();
        youTubeFragmentActivity.setArguments(data);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.main, youTubeFragmentActivity).commit();


        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mainActivity=(MainActivity)activity;
    }


    class Show_data extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

        JSONObject jsonobject;
        JSONArray jsonarray;
        ProgressDialog mDialog;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Bundle bundle = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
             PRO_ID = bundle.getString("PRODUCT_ID");
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://towncitycards.com/webservice_action.php?action=get_detail&id="+PRO_ID);
            try{
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                String data = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());
                jsonobject = new JSONObject(data);  
                jsonarray = new JSONArray(jsonobject.getString("detail"));
                for(int j=0; j<jsonarray.length();j++){
                    JSONObject itemobj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(j);
                    //SHOW SEARCH RESULT
                    Get_detailsBeams get_detailsBeams = new Get_detailsBeams(); 

                    get_detailsBeams.setId(itemobj.getString("ID"));
                    get_detailsBeams.setYoutube(itemobj.getString("youtube_detail"));
                    get_detailsBeams.setTerms_condition(itemobj.getString("terms_condition"));


                    Log.v("Details", itemobj.toString());
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            final String youtube_url;
                try {


                            youtube_url = jobj.opt("youtube_detail").toString();
                            System.out.println("@@@@3@"+youtube_url);
                            youtube_url1=youtube_url.replace("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=","");
                            System.out.println("@@@@3@"+youtube_url1);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if(mDialog!=null && mDialog.isShowing()){
                    mDialog.dismiss();
                }
                }

        }
    }
```

And get it like this:

```
 Bundle extras = getArguments();
 YOU_TUBE = extras.getString("youtube_details");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My problem is that. I am executing `Show_data()` before passing data to
>   fragment. Then why it is given null to bundle.

Because `Show_data()` is an `AsyncTask`, it will run asynchronously. so that `youtube_url1` will be pass to fragment via bundle before assigning it in `onPostExecute`.

> Can I call youtube fragment inside `onPostExecute`?

Yes, you can call & you have to call. Because that is the correct implementation & solution for your question.
Set the `youtube_url1` to bundle in `onPostExecute` & set that bundle to fragment & begin the transaction.

```
String youtube_url;
try {
    youtube_url = jobj.opt("youtube_detail").toString();
    System.out.println("@@@@3@"+youtube_url);
    youtube_url1=youtube_url.replace("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=","");
    System.out.println("@@@@3@"+youtube_url1);
    Bundle data = new Bundle();
    data.putString("youtube_details", youtube_url1);
    YouTubeFragmentActivity youTubeFragmentActivity=new YouTubeFragmentActivity();
    youTubeFragmentActivity.setArguments(data);
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.main, youTubeFragmentActivity).commit();
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
if(mDialog!=null && mDialog.isShowing()) {
    mDialog.dismiss();
}
```

Note from official docs of [AsyncTask execute()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#execute(Params...))

> Note: this function schedules the task on a queue for a single
>   background thread or pool of threads depending on the platform version.

Comment: we have to add " " marks inside `YPlayer.loadVideo("T5RP7E13I-U");` but in my case I am geting `YOU_TUBE = extras.getString("youtube_details");` in the form `T5RP7E13I-U`

Comment: @priya What is your doubt? I can't understand

Comment: Am I have to add double quotes to string I am getting.  Like this: ` YOU_TUBE1= "\"" + YOU_TUBE + "\"";` or not

Comment: @priya Never, no need of quotes, because `youtube_url` itself a String but now only I have noticed the `final` keyword in this `final String youtube_url`.  How can you change the value of a `final`  variable?  Your compiler didn't warn you for leaving the final variable as unassigned at the time of declaring itself?